# How to skip over keys in a python dictionary when looking for a value

Tags: python, python-3.x, amazon-web-services

I'm calling the AWS Pricing API to get the hourly cost of my EC2 instances, and this is an example of what I'm getting for their on-demand prices:

```
{"OnDemand": {
        "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF": {
            "effectiveDate": "2021-08-01T00:00:00Z",
            "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF",
            "priceDimensions": {
                "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                    "appliesTo": [],
                    "beginRange": "0",
                    "description": "$0.0208 per On Demand Linux t3.small Instance Hour",
                    "endRange": "Inf",
                    "pricePerUnit": {
                        "USD": "0.0208000000"
                    },
                    "rateCode": "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
                    "unit": "Hrs"
                }
            },
            "sku": "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR",
            "termAttributes": {}
        }
    }
}
```

My goal is to get the price per unit value and I could easily do that by doing something like:

```
hourly_cost = price_list['OnDemand']['QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF']['priceDimensions']['QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7']['pricePerUnit']['USD']
```

However, keys like "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF" and "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7" are populated randomly for each EC2 instance, so I can't use those two values to retrieve the data for all instances.

I'm looking to find a way to skip over those two keys and get the pricePerUnit.

Comment: Where is the key`['OnDemand']`?

Comment: @It_is_Chris There's key named 'OnDemand' which has the above dictionary as its value

Comment: The dictionary should be `{'OnDemand': {...}}`

Comment: @It_is_Chris I updated the code. I hope it makes more sense now. How would you go on about solving this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `dict.keys()` assuming that the structure is the same

```
k1 = list(d['OnDemand'].keys())[0]
k2 = list(d['OnDemand'][k1]['priceDimensions'].keys())[0]
d['OnDemand'][k1]['priceDimensions'][k2]['pricePerUnit']['USD']
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a regular expression as key for those feilds

```
import re
d[re.compile('[\w]*')]
```

Though using a regular expression as key is not recommended

Answer (score 1):

If recursion is not a problem and this dictionary has data for multiple instances then perhaps converting it into namedtuples might make sense.
Then you can create collection of Instances with their price data. Specially if the price data needs to accessed later multiple times for aggregation with other instances, this might make name referencing easier. Here is a sample code for such an idea.

```
from collections import namedtuple
x = {"OnDemand": {
        "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF": {
            "effectiveDate": "2021-08-01T00:00:00Z",
            "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF",
            "priceDimensions": {
                "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                    "appliesTo": [],
                    "beginRange": "0",
                    "description": "$0.0208 per On Demand Linux t3.small Instance Hour",
                    "endRange": "Inf",
                    "pricePerUnit": {
                        "USD": "0.0208000000"
                    },
                    "rateCode": "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
                    "unit": "Hrs"
                }
            },
            "sku": "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR",
            "termAttributes": {}
        }
    }
}

InstanceData = namedtuple('InstanceData', ['Instancekey','priceDimensions'])
InstancePriceDimensions = namedtuple(
                            'InstancePriceDimensions', 
                            ['InstanceKey', 'PriceDimensionKey','pricePerUnit']
                            )

InstanceDataCollection = []
InstancePriceCollection = []

for key, value in x["OnDemand"].items():
    InstanceDataCollection.append(InstanceData(key, value))
    for x, val in value["priceDimensions"].items():
        if "pricePerUnit" in val:
            InstancePriceCollection.append(
                InstancePriceDimensions(
                                key, 
                                x, 
                                val["pricePerUnit"]
                                )
                )
            
print(InstancePriceCollection)
for x in InstancePriceCollection:
    #aggregate the metric over whole collection or process them
    print(x.pricePerUnit['USD'])
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at he structure of the JSON response I think you have a few options here.

Because the nested objects with keys like `QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF` are essentially wrappers around another sub object you don't necessarily need to worry about searching through a list of objects looking for any or all `pricePerUnit` you can simply access the list of values and pull the first value:

```py
# pulls the value associated with the key `QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF`
outer = list(price_list['OnDemand'].values())[0]

# pulls the value associated with the key `QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7`
inner = list(outer["priceDimensions"].values())[0]

price_per_unit = inner["pricePerUnit"]
```

If the structure of the JSON changes in the future you may need to handle indexing issues with either inner or outer producing an empty list of values, or similarly key errors if the keys themselves change.

Answer (score 0):

There's probably a more concise way to do this and it does rely on the structure being exactly as stated in the question but it works. It differs from the answer given earlier in that it allows for multiple "mystery" keys in any given OnDemand dictionary. Of course, that may not be necessary.

```
D = {'OnDemand': {
    "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF": {
        "effectiveDate": "2021-08-01T00:00:00Z",
        "offerTermCode": "JRTCKXETXF",
        "priceDimensions": {
            "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7": {
                "appliesTo": [],
                "beginRange": "0",
                "description": "$0.0208 per On Demand Linux t3.small Instance Hour",
                "endRange": "Inf",
                "pricePerUnit": {
                    "USD": "0.0208000000"
                },
                "rateCode": "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR.JRTCKXETXF.6YS6EN2CT7",
                "unit": "Hrs"
            }
        },
        "sku": "QA3NBPZEQKZ2K9AR",
        "termAttributes": {}
    }
}
}

base = D['OnDemand']
for b in base.keys():
    pd = base[b]['priceDimensions']
    for d in pd.keys():
        print(pd[d]['pricePerUnit']['USD'])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `dict.values()` to ignore keys:

```
v = lambda d: list(d.values())[0]
hourly_cost = v(v(v(price_list))['priceDimensions'])['pricePerUnit']['USD']
```